# Wordpress Malware: Redirects to Broken Youtube Link

Tags: wordpress, redirect, malware

I have a site I am working on here: `<site url redacted>`

When I go to Case Studies -> Reference Sites it opens a new tab in my browser with the link below. I am using Chrome and it only happens on the first visit (I have to open a new incognito browser each time I want to test it). It has strange Cyrillic characters in the link.

I had this problem with the admin area once before and I removed a bad plugin. This time I have tried deactivating all the plugins and changing to a standard WordPress theme to no avail. I have tried searching the web for this to see if there is a way to remove it and I can't find any reference to it. Could anyone point me in the right direction to a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Bad Link that opens in new tab after navigating from the home page to Case Studies -> Reference Sites:

```
www.youtube.com.channel.uc5hrp.--o1aqy.xnsh7hpar.пчя.ocno1aqy.рф.ig.u4rp66hhp5rocnuolfeo4aig.--o1aqy.яфй.рф/tumbrl.all.7aqy.xn--p1ai.o1aqy.xn--p1ai.myaccount.google.com/imgres/imgurl/?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2FNed_Tu_ge6GgJZ_lIO_5mieIEmjDpq9kfgD05wapmvzcInvT4qQMxhxq_hEaz88Zs9A%3Dw300&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fod%3Dcom.google.androod.youtube%26hl%3Dru&docod=vG8PBuKpiSuZ4M&tbnod=EpkcoX__82qDrM%3A&vet=10ahUKE9jpl4-ilaDZAhXEtRQKHetXBn8QMwg9KAEwAQ..i&w=900&h=300&bih=789&biw=1600&q=aqy.xn--p1ai&ved=0ahUKEwjpl4-ilaDZAhXEtRQKHetXBn8QMwg9KAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=7
```

Comment: First things first: Please don't link to your actual site - there's no reason to. But even moreso when you think you have malware - that's a big red flag, and nobody should be clicking through to your site. That all said: this doesn't look like a programming question.

Comment: So if not a software problem, where is the problem coming from?

Comment: I didn't say it's not a software problem. I'm saying it's not a *programming* problem (and off topic for Stack Overflow). I have no idea how your site got compromised with malware. Seems likely it's a rogue WordPress plugin (as you've already stated you've had plugin issues in the past).

Comment: But I have deactivated all plugins and it still persists

Comment: I really can't tell you why you have malware. But to repeat: this is off topic here. Maybe you can ask on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)? (just don't link to your site if you ask there - knowingly linking to a malware-infested site, in my opinion, is a really bad idea).

Comment: For reference, this would be offtopic at WP Stack Exchange, and short of grabbing the entire codebase of the site it's difficult to near impossible to answer without giving generic advice such as restoring to backups or installing WP Core files over the top of old ones. The OP needs to do an audit of their code and figure out how the attacker got in, something that can't be done here

Answer (score 3):

You're not alone at least. Lots of WordPress sites are affected worldwide.

Remove following files which have been tampered with or uploaded (a search made by the host showed these files had been tampered with):

```
/wp-content/wp-acsessapp.php 
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js 
/wp-includes/wp-jsconfigs.php
/wp-includes/js/jquery-migrate.min.js
```

Also, change all your passwords for users/FTP and so on + update everything.

We also had a new WordPress user with admin rights pop up out of nowhere called "socket". Of course, remove this user.

This is most definitely a script/bot targeting some unknown exploit in either a plugin or Wordpress core. The worst case scenario may happen again if it isn't patched properly.

The only plugin I had installed on our affected site was  "Coming Soon Page & Maintenance Mode by SeedProd" but unclear if that was where the exploit was.

Comment: Had the same problem and identified the same files modified recently and not by me. Took a look at them and seemed suspicious, so I restored a safe backup I had.

Comment: Also, i haven't found wp-jsconfigs.php, the file in wp-content had a slightly different name (wp-acsesapps.php - based on its contents, this seems to be some kind of backdoor that the attacker uses to inject codes to the site) and the footer.php file from my theme was also modified with a code similar to what was found in some of the .js files.

Comment: I'm voting up because I haven't found many information about this attack and the ones i found are recent, so this may be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Also, I have a bunch of other plugins installed but none of them are the one you pointed. And after finding this problem I installed the Wordfence plugin and it was able to tell me what core files were different from the original WP installation, corroborating with what I've already discovered.

Comment: But now I'm scared thinking about how this happened in the first place. Did this happen again to your website, @Daniel?

Comment: Oh, the created admin user in my case was called Header.